# What is the Oracle PL/SQL "--+rule"?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am working with legacy SQL code and I am finding a lot of queries like the following:

```sql
SELECT --+rule
  username,
  usernotes
FROM
  userinfotable
ORDER BY
  username
```

I read the [Oracle Optimizer Hints documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10752/hintsref.htm#21629), but I can't find an exact reference for a `--+rule`. I am thinking this *rule* is possibly an obsolete artifact from a code generation tool that may have been designed to replace "--+rule" with user or generated `/*+ SQL */` hint code.

What do you think?  Does the `--+rule` code [literally] in the above example actually do anything as-is?  or can I just discard it?

Platform = Delphi 6 with Direct Oracle Access components, Oracle 10g2 with last supported updates.  Most of the Legacy SQL code was developed when using Oracle 7 and 8.

Comment: I am used to the rule based optimizer hints looking like this, `/*+ RULE */`. Certainly is a vestige from the past.

Comment: Yes, the SQL code with the `--+rule` in the code were mostly written with Oracle 7 in production at the time.

Comment: It could be worthwhile running an explain plan with and without the query hint. If the rule based optimizer is used, the explain plan should identify this (and try to dissuade you).

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in the referenced documentation you have given:

> The following syntax shows hints contained in both styles of comments
>   that Oracle supports within a statement block.
>
> {DELETE|INSERT|MERGE|SELECT|UPDATE} /*+ hint [text] [hint[text]]... */
>
> or
>
> {DELETE|INSERT|MERGE|SELECT|UPDATE} --+ hint [text] [hint[text]]...
>
> The --+ hint format requires that the hint be on only one line.

So it was an allowed syntax rule for hints: but I think I have never seen it.

In Oracle SQL "rule" hint means use the Rule Based Optimizer (RBO) instead of CBO (Cost Based Optimizer): since Oracle 10 it is no more supported. So for Oracle you cannot discard it: it should be taken into account but without support ...

[10.2 doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10752/whatsnew.htm) says:

> Rule-based Optimization (RBO) Obsolescence
>
> RBO as a functionality is no longer supported. RBO still exists in
>   Oracle 10g Release 1, but is an unsupported feature. No code changes
>   have been made to RBO and no bug fixes are provided. Oracle supports
>   only the query optimizer, and all applications running on Oracle
>   Database 10g Release 1 (10.1) should use that optimizer. Please review
>   the following Oracle Metalink desupport notice (189702.1) for RBO:
>
> http://metalink.oracle.com/metalink/plsql/ml2_documents.showDocument?p_
>   database_id=NOT&p_id=189702.1
>
> You can also access desupport notice 189702.1 and related notices by
>   searching for "desupport of RBO" at:
>
> http://metalink.oracle.com
>
> Notice 189702.1 provides details about the desupport of RBO and the
>   migration of applications based on RBO to query optimization.
>
> Some consequences of the desupport of RBO are:
>
> ```
> CHOOSE and RULE are no longer supported as OPTIMIZER_MODE initialization parameter values and a warning is displayed in the
> ```
>
> alert log if the value is set to RULE or CHOOSE. The functionalities
>   of those parameter values still exist but will be removed in a future
>   release. See "OPTIMIZER_MODE Initialization Parameter" for information
>   optimizer mode parameters.
>       ALL_ROWS is the default value for the OPTIMIZER_MODE initialization parameter.
>       The CHOOSE and RULE optimizer hints are no longer supported. The functionalities of those hints still exist but will be removed in a
>   future release.
>       Existing applications that previously relied on rule-based optimization (RBO) need to be moved to query optimization.

Comment: In this case, the platform is talking to Oracle10g2.  Except for the literal word *rule*, no other code is in the same line after the `--+rule`.  When I test typical queries in TOAD, with and without the `--+rule`, I do not see any significant performance difference.

Comment: In theory you should not discard it. But in practice it is no more supported so better to try to remove it (you can try to compare execution plans if it makes any difference: anyway if DBMS_STATS statistics  exist, they are taken into account and RBO is not).

Comment: Execution time is probably not a bottleneck for the code at this stage.  However, I really want to make sure I won't get *different data output results* if I remove the `--+rule` from the SQL code.

Comment: In theory you can have a different execution plan but it's unlikely because RBO is no more supported. You should not have different result sets. Note that 10.2 is in sustaining support since years - means no more patches - and you should make sure to have 10.2.0.5 release with latest patch set updates.

Comment: The way the select is written with as "select --+rule on" and the column list beginning on the second line indicates it is a comment; if that is the actual code not a reformat for your question.  Probably originating from the (IMHO) vary bad process of just commenting obsolete code but leaving it there.

Comment: My current development is writing new software to replace the old software. I need to retain downlevel compatibility in the new software until it is ready and the old software can be retired. I do not need to change the legacy code. I needed to know if I could remove the `--+rule` or not in the new code. If not used in 10g2.0.4 or later, then I can discard it for all new code - and be sure to remove it when migrating to uplevel Oracle database.